# Zedgraph Hard code axis

Tags: c#, zedgraph

```
tempTime = new DateTime(1989, 1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(tempTime.ToString("HH")) + 1, 0, 0);

string[] labels = new string[(totalMinutes / 60) + 3];
for (int a = 0; a < (totalMinutes / 60) + 3; a++)
{
    tempTime = tempTime.AddHours(1);
    labels[a] = tempTime.ToString("hh") + tempTime.ToString("tt");
}
//for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
//    labels[i] = "" + i * 2;
graph.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text;
graph.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = labels;
```

Above is the code I hard code the zed graph x axis, before I hard code it, this is the graph

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNrm7.png]

After apply the code to hard code, it become like this , please help

Comment: Next time describe a little more what you want to achieve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string XAxis_ScaleFormatEvent(GraphPane pane, Axis axis, double val, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            return "this is 0 index";
        }
        else
        {
            return "else this is not 0 index";
        }
    }
```

found answer, i need to add the event inside format event in the graph , hard code it by each label